# How do I solve tesseract file not found error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tesseract

```
!pip install detecto
!pip install tesseract
!pip install pytesseract

import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"tesseract-ocr/tesseract.exe"

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_image,lang='eng',config='--psm 10 --oem 1 -c 
tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

First I was getting tesseract not in your path error. But I installed the tesseract on the same folder and gave it the path now I am getting the following error. I am working on a jupyter notebook.

Looking at the error it is trying to save to an output file but shouldn't it just return text to the "text" variable?

```
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in run_and_get_output(image, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout, return_bytes)
    270         run_tesseract(**kwargs)
    271         filename = kwargs['output_filename_base'] + extsep + extension
--> 272         with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:
    273             if return_bytes:
    274                 return output_file.read()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tess_0vpg1a42.txt'
```

Comment: Well, *does* that **.txt** file exist in that directory?  If not, where is it?  You need to have that in your path.

Comment: path to "tess_39qj4hw1.txt"?  not sure where that file is ? if it's related to tesseract shouldn't it be inside the "tesseract-ocr/" folder

Comment: *I* would think so, but your run-time system obviously disagrees with us.  Use the file finder functions of your OS.  Also, the StackExchange "superuser" group might be a better place to post this; it's an OS path issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when I try to run `pytesseract.image_to_string()` function (`pytesseract` package installed via `pip` command) in [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) environment with "[Tesseract at UB Mannheim](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki)" installed on Windows.

Trying dig into python wrapper and debug it, I discovered that text file (`/tmp/tess_0vpg1a42.txt` in your case) should be an output from `tesseract.exe` command but if command failed file is not created. In my case, root cause of failure was inability to read temporary created *PNG* file consisting cropped image (in your case `/tmp/tess_0vpg1a42.PNG`) what was not caught by python.

I have no idea why `tesseract.exe` program installed on windows environment can't access file created by python in WSL environment. But I've solved problem by installing `tesseract-ocr` package (`sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr`) on WSL enviroment and using `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract'` in python code.